# K-type in discrete series representation

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, unitary-representations

The following result seems well known.

Let $G$ be a reductive Lie group with a maximal compact subgroup $K$. If $\mu$ is an irreducible unitary representation of $K$, then there exist only finitely many discrete series irreducible unitary representations $\pi$ of $G$ such that $\mu$ appears as a $K$-type in $\pi$.

I do not know where the result was originally showed. I shall be grateful if any expert may offer a reference book or article. Thank you!

Comment: Knapp has something along these lines in ([1986](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=87j:22022), after Corollary 10.37). He points to Harish-Chandra ([1953](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=56610), [1966](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=36:2745)).

Comment: ... and explicitly ([1954](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=62747), Thm 3) where it is called an “immediate consequence of the results proved in ([1953](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=56610))”.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn’t make this an answer, because H-C’s context is slightly different: fixed infinitesimal character. If you can add how it implies what you wanted, don’t hesitate to post that as self-answer. (I haven’t thought about it.)

Comment: It would help if you made more explicit what you mean by "reductive Lie group".(as well as what field you are working over)/

Comment: @JimHumphreys Thank you for your comments, professor Humphreys. I know that there are several versions of the definitions for reductive Lie groups. Actually, when I posted this question, I was not sure about it. Let me just follow the definition in Vogan's book "Representations of Real Reductive Lie Groups", and field is real number field. Also, what if using the other versions of the definitions for reductive Lie groups? For example, just a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ preserved by taking transpose.

Comment: @HebeL Which version of the definition (and field) are you using?

Comment: @JimHumphreys I use the definition as in David Vogan's book "Representations of Real Reductive Lie Groups", where a real reductive Lie group $G$ with a maximal compact subgroup $K$ is defined as: (a) Its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is real reductive; (b) the automorphisms $\mathrm{Ad}(g)$ of $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C}$ are inner for all $g\in G$. (c) There is an involutive automorphism $\theta$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, which gives a decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}+\mathfrak{p}$; (d) The map $K\times\mathfrak{p}\rightarrow G$ is a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the first proof that a K-type occurs at most in finitely many discrete series is in Harish-Chandra

Comment: Discrete Series II, Acta Math 1??

Comment: it would be best to add your comment about a more-precise reference to your answer.

Comment: Check Lemma 70 in Discrete Series II, Acta math. 166, 1966